# set a StyledMapType as an overlayMapType

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I created a custom StyledMapType and insert it in google.maps.overlayMapTypes in order to draw this custom map upon another layer. Unfortunately, I had this javascript error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined main.js:9 
>     (anonymous function) main.js:9 
>     d 
>     L main.js:9 
>     du 
>     H.$ 
>     (anonymous function)

Here is the code I execute in my browser:

```
function initialize() {
  var pinkParksStyles = [
  {
    featureType: "all",
    stylers: [
      { saturation: -80 }
    ]
  },
  {
    featureType: "poi.park",
    stylers: [
      { hue: "#ff0023" },
      { saturation: 40 }
    ]
  }
  ];
  var pinkMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(pinkParksStyles,
    {name: "Pink Parks"});

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.6468, 37.581),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP]
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  //Insert styled map in overlayMapTypes.
  map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, pinkMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP);
}
```

To see a full example, here is a link on jsfiddle code: http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/460/
You can notice in this example that the styled map works as a mapType but not as an overlayMapType.

Thanks,
François

Comment: Can you post a link to your full app or post all your code on jsfiddle? That way we can debug it.

Comment: Thx, here is a link to a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/460/

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure why you would want to do this. Wouldn't it be easier to style a base maptype?
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling#styling_the_default_map

Basically, when you create a maptype to be used in overlayMapTypes it needs to have getTile defined. Check out the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#OverlayMapTypes
a StyledMap doesn't expose that.

Comment: What I really want is to have an overlay with only the main roads, POI or other custom things. I'm already using overlayMapTypes to insert my own tiles but I want to put custom roads and labels over my overlay.

Comment: So you want an overlayMapType that is styled?

Comment: Exactly :). I used a trick to "make" a mapTypes an overlayMapTypes: I retrieve the png url of the mapTypes and create an ImageMapType and use the retrieved url to define getUrl method of ImageMapType.
Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/462/

Comment: Unfortunately, the Google Maps API TOS prohibits direct access of the tiles.

Comment: Yeah, I was not very happy with this trick... and that's why I ask my question :). So, do you know if there is or will be a solution to do correctly an overlayMapType that is styled ?

Comment: Again, not sure why you need to, why not just do an overlay on top of a Google Map? Or use a Static Map with a style?

Comment: My real problem is that my overlay partly hides roads or labels which can be useful to help the user to navigate. To give an example here is a nice map of election in france: http://www.google.fr/elections/ed/fr/results . You can notice that it's not very easy to distinguish labels or roads. It may be not very important for an election map but for other usage, I really think that labels and roads should be upon other overlays, it gives very relevant data and they should be clearly distinguishable.

Comment: Hi, so I suppose that I can't. Maybe I can start only with a label layer just as it is done in https://maps.google.com/ where the labels are place over the traffic layer or other layers.